# sql query display maximum value or all values per customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm beginner , 
i work with SQL Server 2008 R2
i have 3 tables (data base of film library)
customers and film genres,
customers and actors,
customers and directors,
The query that i need to implement is

> "display favorite actor, director , favorite film type(genre)
>   where favorite means that film was rented out the greatest number of times"

a tables that  were  mentioned above had customer's Id ,
customer name (for tables with actors)
actor id , actor name , 
times film with this specific actor was taken by customer,
 the same i have in other tables (favorite film genre, favorite director)

problem is that i have customers which don't have maximum value or have few values with same number i.e. MAX() don't work here .

please if any one can help ?

here is the code for favorite director table :

```
enter code here CREATE VIEW CustFavorDirector AS
SELECT CustTakenFilms.CustomerID ,CustTakenFilms.[Customer Name],
ActorDirector.ParticipantID, ActorDirector.[Participant Name],                   COUNT(ActorDirector.ParticipantID) 'Times was taken' 
FROM 
(
SELECT
Cust.CustomerID,
Cust.FirstName + ' ' + Cust.LastName AS 'Customer Name' ,
Fil.FilmID, Fil.FilmName
FROM
FilmLibrary.dbo.Customer AS Cust
INNER JOIN
FilmLibrary.dbo.Rental AS Rent
ON
Cust.CustomerID = Rent.CustomerID
INNER JOIN
FilmLibrary.dbo.RentalDetails AS RentDet
ON
Rent.RentalID = RentDet.RentalID
INNER JOIN
FilmLibrary.dbo.FilmCopy AS FilCop
ON
RentDet.FilmCopyID = FilCop.FilmCopyID
INNER JOIN
FilmLibrary.dbo.Film AS Fil
ON
FilCop.FilmID = Fil.FilmID
) AS CustTakenFilms
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Film.FilmID, Film.FilmName,Part.ParticipantID , Part.FirstName + ' ' +      Part.LastName AS 'Participant Name', Rol.RoleTypeName
FROM 
FilmLibrary.dbo.Film AS Film
INNER JOIN
FilmLibrary.dbo.FilmDetails AS FilDet
ON
Film.FilmID = FilDet.FilmID
INNER JOIN
FilmLibrary.dbo.Participant AS Part
ON
FilDet.ParticipantID = Part.ParticipantID
INNER JOIN 
FilmLibrary.dbo.RoleType AS Rol
ON
FilDet.RoleTypeID = Rol.RoleTypeID
WHERE Rol.RoleTypeName IN ('Director')
) AS ActorDirector
ON
CustTakenFilms.FilmID = ActorDirector.FilmID
GROUP BY CustTakenFilms.CustomerID , CustTakenFilms.[Customer Name],
ActorDirector.ParticipantID, ActorDirector.[Participant Name]
```

that's what i get when i try to do select on that view:

```
   CustomerID   Customer Name   ParticipantID   Participant Name  Times was taken
    111123     Abel Smith               1        Clark Foster              2
    111123     Abel Smith               15       Philip Morris             2
    111456     Aurora Jones             13       Clay Johnson              2
    111456     Aurora Jones             14       Brittany Walker           1
    111456     Aurora Jones             15       Philip Morris             1
    111789     Alejandro Wil            12       Andrey Konchalovsky       2
    111789     Alejandro Wil            14       Brittany Walker           2
    112123     Ayana Thomas             12       Andrey Konchalovsky       3
    112123     Ayana Thomas             15       Philip Morris             1
    112123     Ayana Thomas             16       Xavier Lonso              1
    113456     Daniel Bell              12       Andrey Konchalovsky       1
    113456     Daniel Bell              13       Clay Johnson              2
    113456     Daniel Bell              14       Brittany Walker           3
    113456     Daniel Bell              15       Philip Morris             1
```

Comment: can you atleast give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: sure , if in column "Times was taken" appear one maximum value i want to display it otherwise if appear few same maximum values that display them all , for example if appear 1,2,3 then display 3 , if appear 1,1,2,2 then display only 2,2 .

Comment: One way you could do it is by getting an aggregate count of the number of times they've gotten any director and add a Row_Number() column Partitioned By the customer and Ordered By the count Desc in a CTE and then return the results where the Row_Number() column equals 1. If you want to try this yourself you'd want to research `Common Table Expressions` and `Windowed Functions`.

Comment: i did something similar with case but it gives me wrong result, for example when user had in column "Times was taken" values 1,2,2 if i try to use MAX() it gives 2 only once but it's not what i'm looking fot it should gives 2 twice . i can't understand how CTE should help me here. as i understand CTE it's some kind of nested table , which i also tried to use and i recived only customers which have the maximum values , whereas i need them all .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take your exact view that you already created, wrap it in a CTE, use a second CTE to get the max for each customer, then join that back to your first CTE, you can get it.  Something like the below:

```
CREATE VIEW CustFavorDirector AS

with CustDirectorRentals as (
    SELECT CustTakenFilms.CustomerID ,CustTakenFilms.[Customer Name],
    ActorDirector.ParticipantID, ActorDirector.[Participant Name],                   COUNT(ActorDirector.ParticipantID) 'Times was taken' 
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT
    Cust.CustomerID,
    Cust.FirstName + ' ' + Cust.LastName AS 'Customer Name' ,
    Fil.FilmID, Fil.FilmName
    FROM
    FilmLibrary.dbo.Customer AS Cust
    INNER JOIN
    FilmLibrary.dbo.Rental AS Rent
    ON
    Cust.CustomerID = Rent.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN
    FilmLibrary.dbo.RentalDetails AS RentDet
    ON
    Rent.RentalID = RentDet.RentalID
    INNER JOIN
    FilmLibrary.dbo.FilmCopy AS FilCop
    ON
    RentDet.FilmCopyID = FilCop.FilmCopyID
    INNER JOIN
    FilmLibrary.dbo.Film AS Fil
    ON
    FilCop.FilmID = Fil.FilmID
    ) AS CustTakenFilms
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT Film.FilmID, Film.FilmName,Part.ParticipantID , Part.FirstName + ' ' +      Part.LastName AS 'Participant Name', Rol.RoleTypeName
    FROM 
    FilmLibrary.dbo.Film AS Film
    INNER JOIN
    FilmLibrary.dbo.FilmDetails AS FilDet
    ON
    Film.FilmID = FilDet.FilmID
    INNER JOIN
    FilmLibrary.dbo.Participant AS Part
    ON
    FilDet.ParticipantID = Part.ParticipantID
    INNER JOIN 
    FilmLibrary.dbo.RoleType AS Rol
    ON
    FilDet.RoleTypeID = Rol.RoleTypeID
    WHERE Rol.RoleTypeName IN ('Director')
    ) AS ActorDirector
    ON
    CustTakenFilms.FilmID = ActorDirector.FilmID
    GROUP BY CustTakenFilms.CustomerID , CustTakenFilms.[Customer Name],
    ActorDirector.ParticipantID, ActorDirector.[Participant Name]
)
, CustMaxRentals AS (
    SELECT  CustomerID, max([Times was taken]) AS MaxTimesTaken
    FROM    CustDirectorRentals
)
SELECT  cdr.*
FROM    CustDirectorRentals cdr
        JOIN CustMaxRentals cmr ON cdr.CutomerId = cmr.CustomerId AND cdr.[Times was taken] = cmr.MaxTimesTaken;
```